# java Validations to check if more than one textbox has values

Tags: java

I have three text boxes in my html ,where user can input values. In my java class i am doing validations to check if more than one input box has been entered .If user has entered values in two/three textboxes i need to throw an error message. If he hasnt entered the value in three textboxes also i am planning to throw error messsagae. My code is something like this .

```
      if(!dId.equals("") && !PId.equals("") && !PPup.equals("")){
        result.addError(new ErrorBO("only one should only be entered"));
    }

    if(dId.equals("") && PId.equals("") && PPup.equals("")){
        result.addError(new ErrorBO(" one should  be entered"));
    }
```

dId,PId,PPup are the variables where i have my values. This code fails for the case where the user enters the value in two text boxes. Is there a simplified way to check all the cases.

Comment: I would advise setting an int counter=0 and writing three if's that will ++ it if the id is nonempty. Then see if the counter==1 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numEntered = 0
if(!dId.equals("")) numEntered ++; 
if(!pId.equals("")) numEntered ++;
if(!pPup.equals("")) numEntered ++;
if(numEntered != 1) result.addError(new ErrorBO("Enter values in one text box"));
```

Basically, increase a counter every time a text box has entry. If anything but 1 of them has text, return your error.